# Creating components from array of objects in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, mvvm, vue.js, vuejs2, web-frontend

I'm stuck trying to create multiple components from an array of objects.

What the app is supposed to do is loop through an array of answers, and spit out a single-answer component for each one. It currently does not, but I get no error messages in the console.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#quiz',
  data: {
    question: 'Which answer is the correct one?',
    answers: [
      {text: 'This one', correct: true},
      {text: 'Or this one', correct: false}
    ]
  }
});

Vue.component('single-answer', {
  props: ['answer'],
  template: '<div>{{ answer.text }}</div>'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="quiz">
  <h3>{{ question }}</h3>
  <single-answer v-for="(answer, index) in answers" :answer="answer" :key="index"></single-answer>
</div>
```

Comment: Register your component before instantiating Vue.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!